# What is the connection between number of permutations and number of subsets?

Tags: permutations

How many different ways to fill 100 boxes in a line with black or white balls. 
(One box can only contain one ball at a time.)

My attempt :

Different ways to fill 1 st box = 2
Different ways to fill 2 nd box = 2
Different ways to fill 3 rd box = 2
'
'
'
'
'
Different ways to fill 99th box = 2
Different ways to fill 100th box = 2

SO by method of counting the answer is $2^{100}$.

This is same as number of subsets a set of 100 elements has?

What is the connection this type of questions and $2^n$ has?

Comment: A filling is uniquely determined by the choice of the subset of boxes containing black balls.

Comment: You mention permutations in the title but I don't see anything about permutations in your actual question.

Comment: Also [a duplicate of this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/236659/11619).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of subsets of a set having r elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236659/number-of-subsets-of-a-set-having-r-elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A subset $B$ of a set $A$ can be thought of by the following scheme:

If $x \in A$ then either $x \in B$ or $x\notin B$. So for each element we have these two choices, and we must make such a choice for each element. This is exactly what you did except in this case the choice was black or white.

Comment: Short and satisfying