# Please explain how to do/calculate/read this Sigma notation?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, notation, binomial-coefficients

Can anyone tell me what this notation means?

$2^n = \sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}$

That would be great, Thanks!
For more Information go to [Number of subsets of a set having r elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236659/number-of-subsets-of-a-set-having-r-elements).

Comment: Are you familiar with binomial coefficients and Pascal's triangle?

Comment: @DreiCleaner no

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Comment: I do not think this question should be closed. The current answer explains the three pieces of notation being used, so I don't think any more clarity or detail is needed. Also, as a question type, asking about notation is fine.

Answer (score 8):

I'll go through each piece of notation in turn:

- $2^n$ is hopefully familiar notation. It means
  $\underbrace{2 \times 2 \times \ldots \times 2}_{n \text{ times}}$
- $\binom{n}{r}$ is a [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). It is an abbreviation for $\dfrac{n!}{r! (n-r)!}$. Again, hopefully [factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) are familiar to you.
- $\sum_{r=0}^n a_r$ means to add up the terms $a_r$ from $r=0$ to $r=n$. So it abbreviates $a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_{n-1} + a_n$.

Let's do a small example of your exact question:

For $n=2$, the equation reads

$$2^2 = \sum_{r=0}^2 \binom{2}{r}$$

The left hand side is $4$, and the right hand side is

$$\binom{2}{0} + \binom{2}{1} + \binom{2}{2} = 1 + 2 + 1 = 4$$

And we see that the two sides are equal.

As an exercise, can you explicitly write out what the $n=3$ case says?

---

I hope this helps ^_^